# How to get a recursive function to return false if infinite recursion occurs

Tags: java, recursion

This is the problem I have:

http://codingbat.com/prob/p185204

Try and split an array into two of equal sum. If possible, return true, else return false.

This is my logic:

given {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} {}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} {7}
{2, 3, 4, 5, 6} {7, 1}
{3, 4, 5, 6} {7, 1, 2}
{4, 5, 6} {7, 1, 2, 3}
{5, 6} {7, 1, 2, 3, 4}
{5, 6, 1} {7, 2, 3, 4}
{5, 6, 1, 2} {7, 3, 4}

true
```

but if there is no possible way to split it to get 2 equal sums, it'll go into an infinite recursion. Recursion is a requirement for this. All I need is a way to check if it's going into an infinite recursion and have it return false.

EDIT: here's some psuedo-code to hopefully help get what I'm trying to do across.

```
2ndArray.add(largest from 1stArray)

public attemptSplit(using 1stArray and 2ndArray)

if (1st array and 2nd array aren't equal)
    get the smallest value from the array with larger sum,
    and move it to the other array
else
    attempSplit(using the two new arrays)    //<-this is where the recursive part comes in
```

So, I have the base case for when it's true, that's easy. I need a base case for when it's false.

Comment: I'm going to give you some credit here: I assume you don't want to *actually* wait and see if it runs for infinity (which is, by definition, impossible to do), but rather that you want to *predict* whether it will go into infinite recursion. Right?

Comment: All very funny... but I think there may be a legitimate question here, badly stated.  Sometimes you do need to know how to avoid a situation where a recursive function f(a) calls f(b) that ultimately calls f(a).  I've run into problems like that, where the solution is essentially to use something like a `Set` to track what you've already tried.  But I don't see offhand why this would be a problem with the poster's algorithm.

Comment: @JediCreed94: The description of your algorithm is rather fuzzy, and I don't see where it involves recursion at all.  Perhaps something more spelled-out, either actual code or pseudo-code, would be helpful.  My gut feeling about this is that if your algorithm recurses infinitely when there's no solution, there's some fundamental error in your algorithm.

Comment: The number of ways you can distribute x numbered balls in two buckets is not infinite unless the x is infinite.

Comment: @ajb: The reason I did not respect this question (and voted to closed it and commented with a joke) is not that it is badly stated, but that the actual question is not stated at all. The OP’s problem is not that infinite recursion is possible but that they do not have any sensible algorithm. “Move the smallest number from the larger group” is not even a basis for starting. This is beyond the Stack Overflow format; they need a tutor or other training. And, unfortunately, several people have attempted to answer the title question as if it were literally asking to solve the Halting Problem.

Comment: People should vote to close. The OP should either, for a while, work on exercises they are prepared to tackle on their own or seek other ways of learning, such as taking a class or following a textbook.

Comment: @ajb: I hope the edits help. If not, let me know what I can do to help you help me. I'm still new to the whole forum thing and what people expect of me from here.

Comment: @Sylwester: I don't literally mean it's infinite. I mean that it gets to a point, if there are no solutions, where it just keeps swapping the same lowest number between the two arrays over and over because it got the sums as close as they could get but there is no way to get the two arrays to be of equal sum. I want to know how to get the recursive loop to terminate if there is no solution.

Comment: @ Jean-Francois Corbett: firstly, sorry for not using the cedilla. haha but yes of course. For instance, if the set is odd, then of course it wouldn't be able to split into two sets of equal sum, nor could it if the largest value in the set is larger than half the total sum. There are other cases beyond these though that should still return a false, and I'm looking for how to catch those.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Maybe you are right about voting to have it closed, but I am taking a class for this (Java to be specific), and doing pretty well I might add. I'm still learning though (obviously) and I can assure you, this isn't the first nor will it be the last time I'm dead wrong about how to go about solving a problem. If you could just bear with me on this one and let me know what I can learn from this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the title of your question is **you cannot**.

The answer to the body of your question is - you've got it wrong - you won't hit infinite recursion, you will just finish all possibilities. At that point you can return `false` having tried each one and found none satisfying your criteria.

All you need to do is work out an algorithm that will iterate through all possibilities. This can be done with something like:

```
for each entry - 
  move it to the other set
  check to see if you have found an answer and if so report it and finish
  recurse on your new smaller set
  move it back
```

Comment: Regarding the first sentence in this answer, the OP is not actually asking to solve the Halting Problem; alluding to it may mislead them. Regarding the pseudo-code, it is inadequate since it only performs a check during the period when the entry is in “the other set”. It would be necessary to check once with the entry in the first set and once with the entry in the second set.

Comment: ugh... so I will have to have my program just try each and every possible combination? I thought I was being clever and found a relatively short way to get to the answer of two equal sums if there was such a possibility with the given set.

Comment: @JediCreed94 - If you haven't tried all of them how can you be sure there aren't any solutions?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: er.. let me preface this response with, I'm most likely wrong, but I figured if you keep changing the sets using the smallest value possible, then you'll eventually get to the solution, if there is one. I'm not sure how to completely explain what I'm picturing. I did the best I could with the example I gave :\

Comment: @JediCreed94 - I can assure you that whatever algorithm you choose, if it does not ultimately iterate across all permutations there will be some insane input that will make it say no when it should say yes.

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach to curbing rampant recursion is to include a depth argument to the function call and increment it each time you recurse.

The first thing your function should do is check that the depth has not crossed a limit that you think would be unlikely to happen except in the case of an infinite recursion trap.

Then you throw an exception or at least stop the tailspin before the stack overflows.

EDIT: The other responders are correct, however, that your algorithm is flawed and a correct solution to this problem would require no such failsafe.

Comment: I wish I could vote you up, but I need more rep :\ I had thought about this depth argument, and possibly calculating the maximum possible steps needed given the size and total sum of the initial array, but I couldn't think of the algorithm to find that value either, so it became moot. ugggh... back to the drawing board I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to decide, with a program, whether another program will end or not.

More information can be found on it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

As for the actual question: You will need to think up another approach.
Perhaps you can (for **this** problem only) decide that it is going into infinite recursion if your method has done a certain number of moves.

Comment: The OP is not actually asking to solve the Halting Problem; referring to this without explanation may mislead them.

Answer (score 0):

```
public attemptSplit(using 1stArray and 2ndArray)

if (1st array and 2nd array aren't equal)
    get the smallest value from the array with larger sum,
    and move it to the other array
else
    attempSplit(using the two new arrays)    //<-this is where the recursive part comes in
```

OK, that's more information, but it's still somewhat confusing.  The way this is written, if the 1st array and 2nd array *are* equal (I assume you mean the sums), which is the "else" part of your pseudo-code, I think this is when you want to return true since you've found a solution--you wouldn't want to recurse again.

Maybe you meant something like this?

```
if (1st array and 2nd array aren't equal)
    get the smallest value from the array with larger sum,
    and move it to the other array
    attempSplit(using the two new arrays)
else
    return true
```

There's an obvious problem here, that there's nothing in your algorithm that ever returns false.  But the less obvious problem is that this approach just won't work, if I understand what you're trying to do; it could recurse infinitely even when the result should be true.  Try with {1, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11}; it looks like your approach is to pull out the largest number into your first set:

```
{1, 3, 6, 7, 10}       {11}
```

Then if the two sets have different sums, determine which set has the larger sum, and move the smallest number from that set to the other.  This will give

```
{3, 6, 7, 10}          {11, 1}
{6, 7, 10}             {11, 1, 3}
{7, 10}                {11, 1, 3, 6}  -- now the right-hand set has a larger sum
{1, 7, 10}             {11, 3, 6}
{1, 3, 7, 10}          {11, 6}        -- now the left-hand set is larger
{3, 7, 10}             {11, 1, 6}
{7, 10}                {11, 1, 3, 6}
```

and you're in an infinite loop now.  You never get 11 and 7 together in the same set, which you need to do to solve the problem.  Perhaps I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, and maybe you left some steps out; but I think your approach is faulty.

Here's an outline of how I'd approach it: I'm assuming all the array elements are positive integers.  First of all, if the sum of the entire array is N, and you can split it into two parts with equals sums, each part will add to N/2.  If N is odd, just give up.  Otherwise, try to find a subset whose sum is N/2.  You can do this with recursion by writing a recursive routine `findSubset(S,M)` which finds a subset of S whose sum is M.  To do this: Assume S1, S2, S3, ... are the elements of S in order.  If one of the elements equals M, then you've found a one-element subset.  If M<=0 or all the elements of S are larger than M, or if S is empty, then fail.  Else: try `findSubset({S2,S3, ...}, M-S1)`; if that doesn't work, `findSubset({S3,S4,...}, M-S2)`; if that doesn't work, `findSubset({S4,S5,...},M-S3)`, and so on.

Comment: Nope, you nailed it. I was completely wrong about how to go about this. Thanks for that example. I just couldn't think of a set that proved my logic wrong, so I ran with it. Vote to close this thread I suppose. Thanks for the tip on how to rightly go about it though, you were a lot of help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just evenly divide the numbers and rely on only the lowest to split.. Actually it could be that one of the larger elements need to switch with several of the smaller numbers in solutions. You need to be able to iterate over all the possible permutations!

So every element can either be in the first bucket or the second so you could have a number representing if one element is in either bucket 0 or bucket 1. An integer has 32 bits, but we need to reserve two bits. Thus this will work for an array with 0-30 elements:

```
/** Find how to split an array of integers
    into two even groups.

    @param lst array of elements to be split
    @return the bitmask or -1 if no solution exist
**/
public static int findSplit( int[] lst )
{
  int lstLen = lst.length;
  int maxMask = 1 << lstLen;
  for(int mask=0; mask < maxMask; mask++) {
    int[] c = {0,0};
    for(int i=0, curMask=mask; i < lstLen; i++, curMask>>=1 ) {
      c[curMask&1]+= lst[i];
    }
    if( c[0] == c[1] )
      return mask;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

This will not solve you problem since you are required to use recursion, but both for loops can easily be replaced with one helper function.

Comment: Yeaaa I realize that now. My logic was just absolutely.. well, not logical haha thanks for being patient with me and helping. I wish I could upvote you and ajb.